# Is it possible to remove the Add option from the calendar view?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, calendar

I have created sharePoint Calendar list and I want to remove the Add option which comes as default in the calendar view.

Comment: Do you want to prevent users from adding new items to the calendar list?

Answer (score 0):

you can use css, either add it to your custom style sheet or to a CEWP

```
table.ms-acal-vcont tbody tr td a {display:none !important;}
```